# SpriteBatch.end() Issue because of a thread

Tags: xna, c#, multithreading, spritebatch

While playing, I use a thread to `Load()` and `Unload()` `Texture2D`.
I have multiple `ContentManager` to only `Unload()` `Texture2D` I want to unload.

But sometimes, I have this issue on the `SpriteBatch.End()` :

```
    ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a disposed object
    Object name : texture2D
```

I don't understand very well the `Threads`, and I think it's the main problem.
Roughly :

```
    Game.Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        character.Update(gameTime);
        //...Things.Update(gameTime)...
        CheckThingsToLoadandUnload();
    //etc
    }

    CheckThingsToLoadAndUnload()
    {
        For each texture to check
        {
            if(HasPrerequists)
            {
                if(!thisTexture.isLoaded)
                {
                    ThreadStart ths_LoadInGame = delegate {
                        LoadInGame(param1, param2, param3); };
                    new Thread(ths_LoadInGame).Start();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if(thisTexture.isLoaded)
                {
                    ThreadStart ths_UnloadInGame = delegate {
                        UnloadInGame (param1, param2); };
                    new Thread(ths_UnloadInGame ).Start();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I overrided the `T Load<T<(string assetname)` `ContentManager` to add a `Lock`.

I think this issue happens when the `Unload() Thread` unload a Texture used by the SpriteBatch().
But I really don't know how to prevent this.
Hope you can help.

Comment: Just because the CPU portion of a Draw call has completed doesn't mean the GPU has finished rendering. Any textures used in the last Draw call could still be in memory and in use on the GPU. You will want to delay disposing any textures for at least a few draw calls after they were last used.

Comment: You will also not want to spawn a new thread for loading and unloading each individual asset. The overhead of spawning threads is too high. It would be much better to have one dedicated thread handling loading and unloading of assets, but even then you need to be aware of graphic device locks negating your threaded logic. See here http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnhar/archive/2008/05/23/lock-contention-during-load-screen-animations.aspx

Comment: @dadooGames How to know if the Texture-I-want-to-unload is in use on the gpu ?
With my example, how to keep a thread on ? Sorry, but I feel lost. (about your link, yes, I already use this for my loading screen)

Comment: @dadooGames I don't think the base.draw() method returns before the GPU is finished. As far as I know XNA does not use a form of threaded rendering. Do you have a source for this?

Comment: In XNA, Draw() won't return until all the appropriate commands are sent to the GPU, but it does not wait for the GPU to execute them before moving on to the next frame. I can't find a good reference, other than this slightly related link that is all about XNA without saying XNA at all http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnhar/archive/2008/03/31/an-elf-in-a-box.aspx

Comment: @Sharpnel You can't know, for certain. You could track the number of Draw calls since your texture was last drawn and after a few have passed then try disposing it. Not very scientific, but it will work.

Comment: @dadooGames Ok, I added only one background thread with an infinite controled loop (and a sleeptime) (created during the loading level screen) which Load and unload assets. But I still have difficulties to understand your advice. Could you post an answer with a bit of pseudo-code please ? thx for your time.

Comment: Don't use threads until you understand them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the participation of "dadoo Games", here is my answer.

Thread :

```
Unload()
{
   if(canUnload) { UnloadTextures() }
}
```

DrawMethod :

```
Draw(GameTime gameTime)
{
    canUnload = false;
    DrawScenes();
    base.Draw(GameTime);
    canUload = true;
```